# Prevent hash tag jump

Tags: javascript, hash, tags

For example I have an address http://address.com/#tag

I want to remove redirection to tag element when the page is loaded? I saw some solutions but they work when you process request before sending it. I would like to prevent this behaviour when the page is loaded.

Comment: this will work only if you have an element with `#id` in that page

Comment: Jumping to the specified element is what that URL syntax is designed for. If you aren't doing that, what are you doing instead?

Comment: A hashtag is a means of indicating that a term, in plain text, should be hyperlinked to a search engine on social media networks. It gets the name because it it uses a hash character to prefix it. Please don’t confuse other uses of the hash character with hashtags.

Comment: i want to wait until all images are loaded, because it redirects to the wrong place

Answer (score 0):

I would navigate the first element before the page is done loading, and as the page and all the images are done loading, I would navigate again to the desired id.

In the following example, tested in Chrome for Windows, calling the page with `#two` will only navigate to that id after the page and all the "images" are loaded. `setTimeout` here simulates the loading.

```
<div id='one' style='height:800px;'>
Line one
</div>
<div id='two' style='height:800px;'>
Line two
</div>

<script>
location = '#one'; // that redirects to the top of the page
setTimeout(whenImagesLoaded, 4000);

function whenImagesLoaded () {
  location = '#two'; // that redirects back to the original request
}
</script>
```